# Problems with srand(), C++

Tags: c++, srand

I'm trying to write a program that generates a pseudorandom numbers using a seed. However, I'm running into problems.

I get this error

```
39 C:\Dev-Cpp\srand_prg.cpp void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Using this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream> 
#include <limits>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std ;

int main(){
    int rand_int;
    string close ;

    close == "y" ;

    cout << endl << endl ;
    cout << "\t ___________________________________" << endl ;
    cout << "\t|                                   |" << endl ;
    cout << "\t|   Pseudorandom Number Game!       |" << endl ;
    cout << "\t|___________________________________|" << endl ;
    cout << endl << endl ;

    while ( close != "y" ){

        rand_int = srand(9);
        cout << rand_int << endl ;

        cout << "  Do you wish to exit the program? [y/n]     " ;
        cin >> close ; }

}
```

Comment: Lots of good answers below. For future reference, the compiler message "void value not ignored as it ought to be" tells you: "you are using the result of a function that's defined not to return anything ('void')". That usually means you should check the documentation on how the function's supposed to be used, because what you're trying isn't correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`srand` doesn't return a random number, it just reseeds the random number generator.  Call `rand` afterwards to actually get a number:

```
srand(9);
rand_int = rand();
```

Answer (score 4):

srand() generates a seed (which is the number used to initialize the random number generator) and must be called once per process. rand() is the function you are looking for.

If you don't know what seed to pick, use the current time:

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // include <ctime> to use time()
```

Answer (score 3):

call it this way.

```
srand(9);
rand_int = rand();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `srand` incorrectly, that particular function is for setting the seed for later calls to `rand`.

The basic idea is to call `srand` once with an indeterminate seed, then call `rand` continuously to get a sequence of numbers. Something like:

```
srand (time (0));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << (rand() % 10);
```

which should give you some random numbers between 0 and 9 inclusive.

You generally don't set the seed to a specific value unless you're testing or you want an identical sequence of numbers for some other reason. You also don't set the seed each time before you call `rand` since you're likely to get the same number repeatedly.

So your particular `while` loop would be more like:

```
srand (9); // or use time(0) for different sequence each time.
while (close != "y") {  // for 1 thru 9 inclusive.
    rand_int = rand() % 9 + 1;
    cout << rand_int << endl;

    cout << "Do you wish to exit the program? [y/n]? ";
    cin >> close;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

srand returns void function and doesn't return a value.

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) you can see more about it. You'll just have to call srand(9) and get the value of rand() after that, like J-16 SDiZ pointed out, who will be upvoted for this :)